# Add a class to the HTML <body> tag with React?

Tags: html, reactjs, classname

I'm making a modal in my React project that requires a class to be added to the body when the modal is open and removed when it is closed.

I could do this the old jQuery way by running some vanilla JavaScript which adds / removes a class, however this doesn't feel like the normal React philosophy.

Should I instead setState on my top level component to say whether the modal is open or closed? Even if I did this, as it's rendered into the div on the page it's still a side-effect to edit the body element, so is there any benefit for this extra wiring?

Comment: It might help to have a top-level container instead of directly manipulating the body tag.

Comment: I prefer `some vanilla javascript`, you can add class in `componentDidMount` and remove in `componentWillUnmount`, `mousewheel` is global and not `React philosophy`, still you use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add or remove a className on event in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732253/how-to-add-or-remove-a-classname-on-event-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

***TL;DR*** use `document.body.classList.add` and `document.body.classList.remove`

I would have two functions that toggle a piece of state to show/hide the modal within your outer component.

Inside these functions I would use the `document.body.classList.add` and `document.body.classList.remove` methods to manipulate the body class dependant on the modal's state like below:

```
openModal = (event) => {
  document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
  this.setState({ showModal: true });
}
hideModal = (event) => {
  document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
  this.setState({ showModal: false });
}
```

Comment: I wonder if modifying the `<body>` element is a so-called `side effect` in React Framework. If it is, should I put the logic in `useEffect` hook?

Answer (score 47):

With the new React (16.8) this can be solved with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html):

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

const addBodyClass = className => document.body.classList.add(className);
const removeBodyClass = className => document.body.classList.remove(className);

export default function useBodyClass(className) {
    useEffect(
        () => {
            // Set up
            className instanceof Array ? className.map(addBodyClass) : addBodyClass(className);

            // Clean up
            return () => {
                className instanceof Array
                    ? className.map(removeBodyClass)
                    : removeBodyClass(className);
            };
        },
        [className]
    );
}
```

then, in the component

```
export const Sidebar = ({position = 'left', children}) => {
    useBodyClass(`page--sidebar-${position}`);
    return (
        <aside className="...">
            {children}
        </aside>
    );
};
```

Comment: 16.8, not 16.9 :)

Comment: This doesn't remove the previous body class on navigation for me. Every page component that mounts just adds the class to the body

Comment: @user3869231 not sure where the problem might be but for me it seems to be working fine, see https://codesandbox.io/s/usebodyclass-v59mkt?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 29):

Actually you don't need 2 functions for opening and closing, you could use `document.body.classList.toggle`

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('modal-open', isOpen);
},[isOpen])
    
<button onCLick={()=> setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>Toggle Modal</button>
```

Comment: Replace isMobileOpen with isOpen: `document.body.classList.toggle('modal-open', isOpen);`

Comment: I would also add a cleanup function `return () => document.body.classList.remove('modal-open')` within the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 1):

Like what @brian mentioned, try having a top-level container component that wraps around your other components. (assuming you're not using redux in your app)

In this top-level component:

1. Add a boolean state (eg. `modalOpen`) to toggle the CSS class
2. Add methods (eg. `handleOpenModal` & `handleCloseModal`) to modify the boolean state.
3. Pass the methods created above as props into your `<Modal />` component

Answer (score -7):

ReactJS has an official React Modal component, I would just use that: https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal