# React JS - How better to add React component to ReactDOM

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is it okay if I insert React component directly in document body by id?

Or it is better to wrap it in DIV?

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store()}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector("#root")
)
```

**index.html**

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100" id="root">
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
</body>
```

Comment: No need for an extra div in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend to use `body` as root of the virtual DOM for 3 reasons:

1. `body` normally contains script tags, which might include your React logic. Rerendering `body` means that you need to take care of all your scripts too, and everytime `body` needs to be re-rendered, all your scripts need to be reload again, which is not efficient, not to mention side effect of reloading React code (which I don't have any experience to justify). The only way to avoid this is to put all your scripts into `header`, [which is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531534/2404452).
2. If you need to modify `body`, e.g. adding classes "modal-open" if you use Bootstrap modal, there are other solutions like [using React's hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537134/2404452) or an event listener dedicated to updating body.
3. Normally a web application product does not only use a DOM manipulator script, but also other scripts for business purposes (e.g. Google Analytics, Analytics.js, Google map). There are apps which contains more than 1 React script working independently. In those cases, the script logic should be separated and not coupled together. If there are 2 React scripts, the 2 root nodes should not be nested to avoid unneeded re-render.

Answer (score 0):

In my html page I only use one `<div id="root">`

After that:

```
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

does all the magic.

reference:  https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html