# Darkmode not working on tailwind headless UI

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

Darkmode works everywhere in my react app, except on a headless ui combobox. I put a styled h1 in the same component and applied `dark:bg-red-200`(and any other style) no problem. The combobox accept all other tailwind utilities including attibutes like `hover:` but not the `dark:` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### For others (such as me) stumbling upon this:

- E.g. the `Dialog`-component (and I assume others too) render right in the body tag ([source](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/558#issuecomment-850407574))
- If you are using ["the class strategy"](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#supporting-system-preference-and-manual-selection) to handle dark mode (i.e. adding a "dark" class to the wrapper) this will be a problem, because that class is not anymore parent to the `Dialog` (because your wrapper is also only a child to the body)

##### Solution I ended up using:

I ended up using useEffect to [add the dark class to the body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47707511/3763660):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(darkMode){
    document.body.classList.add('dark')
  }else{
    document.body.classList.remove('dark')
  }
}, [darkMode])
```

Answer (score 1):

**VueJs Problem:**

I believe this happens because the Dialog(modal) is part of the built files which are auto injected.

**VueJS Solution:**

I just stumbled on a similar issue with vue and fixed it by adding a similar variable i added to my `App` wrapper in the scoped component, `:class="isDark ? 'dark' : ''"` as follows:

```html
  <Dialog
      :class="isDark ? 'dark' : ''"
      as="div"
      class="relative z-[1000]"
      @close="modalOpen = false"
    >
</Dialog>
```

Note that in my code `isDark` is a boolean variable which comes from the store. also have a watcher around it to listen to changes in theme.

```js
 data() {
    return {
      isDark: this.$store.getters.getIsDark,
    };
  },
```

My watcher:

```js
watch: {
   // whenever isDark changes, this function will run
   "$store.state.isDark": function () {
     this.isDark = this.$store.state.isDark;
   },
},
```

Works like charm!