# Like dislike button react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make my toggle like dislike icon work, but seems like the conversion from like to dislike isn't working. Anyone can have a look at my code and tell me what's wrong?

---

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import "./Card.css"

class Card extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("fa-thumbs-down");
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="cardbox">
                    <div className="cardtitle">{this.props.title}</div>
                    <div>{this.props.category}</div>
                    <div>{this.props.likes / this.props.dislikes}</div>
                    <i onclick={this.myFunction(this)} className="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                </div>    
        )
    }
}

export default Card
```

Comment: How do you pass the `props` to `<Card>` component? Can you please share that part of your code as well? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, why don't you have a state which regulates this? You could do something in there then like ```toggle() { this.setState(prevState => ({ like: !prevState.like }) }```

Comment: If you're going to use react, you shouldn't be directly changing the DOM. The problems are: 1) `onclick` is not valid in JSX, its `onClick`. 2) You're immediately calling `myFunction` not passing its reference to the handler. 3) Utilize state, and change the className based on the state value instead of doing `classList.toggle`.

Comment: Also, if you need `this` in a function, either bind it to `this` or make it an arrow function. Passing `this` as an argument seems hacky.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add or remove a className on event in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732253/how-to-add-or-remove-a-classname-on-event-in-reactjs)

Comment: @BrianThompson and OP is not just passing `this`, he is calling it immediately, defeating the purpose of the callback altogether.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yeah I caught that and edited my comment

Comment: can someone maybe explain how you change the className based on the state value (instead of doing classlist.toggle)