# ReactJS onclick add or remove class to another element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I am struggling to convert my normal jQuery code in to React JS (I'm new to React).

I have the following code:

```js
$(".add").click(function () {
    $("nav").addClass("show");
});
$(".remove").click(function () {
    $("nav").removeClass("show");
});
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $("nav").toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
nav.show {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">Add</button>
<button class="remove">Remove</button>
<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
<nav>Navigation menu</nav>
```

Tried references seems that only add/remove class for the same element:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42630743/6191987

[How to add or remove a className on event in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28732253/6191987)

So, how can I convert or create the same jQuery methods to ReactJS?

Comment: Please show us what have you attempted in React so far.

Comment: @SibasishMohanty Already added references, but that wont't help for my case. I mentioned I am new to React JS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use the state that keeps the track of whether to show the nav or not.
2. Use a class name in the react code that corresponds to the state.
3. React uses "className" instead of "class" since "class" is already a reserved word in javascript.

You could check this [sandbox link for implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-sanne-uuigt?file=/src/App.js)

```
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button className="add" onClick={() => setShow(true)}>
        Add
      </button>
      <button className="remove" onClick={() => setShow(false)}>
        Remove
      </button>
      <button className="toggle" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
        Toggle
      </button>
      <nav className={show ? "show" : ""}>Navigation menu</nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: <nav class="menu"> has already a class "menu", so how can I write this: `className={show ? "show" : ""}` (need existing class to the code)

Comment: @vishnu you could use template strings. Since classNames are strings, you could concatenate them. `<nav className={`nav ${show ? "show" : ""}`}>Navigation menu</nav>`

Comment: @vishnu I have also made changes to the code sandbox link. You could check there as well.

Comment: this works for me.. I appreciate your great support

Answer (score 3):

You could combine the use `useRef` for `nav` and manipulate the ref (accessing `nav`'s DOM) with event handlers for each button

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const navRef = React.useRef(null);

  const onAddClick = (e) => {
    navRef.current.classList.add("show");
  };

  const onRemoveClick = (e) => {
    navRef.current.classList.remove("show");
  };

  const onToggleClick = (e) => {
    navRef.current.classList.toggle("show");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onAddClick}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={onRemoveClick}>Remove</button>
      <button onClick={onToggleClick}>Toggle</button>
      <nav ref={navRef}>Navigation menu</nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

nav.show {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

Codesanbox link for demo

[image: Edit objective-framework-lpl9e]

Reference:

- [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)
- [useRef doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)
- [Element.classList doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Shows a Type error: "Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

Comment: @vishnu have you tried like what is implemented in codesandbox link?

Comment: @vishnu could you send me the screenshot of your code through imgur link?

Comment: Error scrn.shot: [https://imgur.com/a/i1GlDcQ](https://imgur.com/a/i1GlDcQ)

Comment: @vishnu thanks but I meant the code, not the error, it could be better if I could glance at the part of the code to check what was going on

Comment: I'm really sorry, I do not have permission to share the code.. I know it would be difficult to solve this problem without code.. Actually, it is for create a custom open close navigation menu on mobile.. that's what I needed

Comment: @vishnu are you push three of these event handlers in the Component's function, I saw in the image you sent me, seems like you put those outside of the Component function's scope

Comment: added inside of the component function..!

Comment: I edited the answer, it should fully look like above. Please try one more time and check if it worked

Comment: sure.. let me try.. I really appreciate your great support.. :)

Comment: It is working perfectly on a "div" element but not in "nav".. I don't know why this happened

Comment: @vishnu I've just added the `style.css` file, please have a look and try