# How to add class after onclick Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on Reactjs,I have list of questions(using loop) with radio button
and i want to add class on radio button which clicked,But right now unable to add class,
Here is my current code

```
<FormControlLabel
                    key={`radio${item.id}${count + 2}`}
                    value={item.id.toString()}
                    control={<Radio color="primary" required={item.required} />}
                    label={getChoice(item)}
                    onClick={myfunct}
                  />
                ))}
```

And in juqery i am using following code

```
   const myfunct = event => {
         $(this).addClass('my-selected-item');
     }
```

Comment: Mixing jQuery and React is a recipe for a lot of headaches. React already has good ways of dealing with state management and styles, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63465569/5774952).

Answer (score 1):

it is not good idea to change DOM elements directly like this. Better store the status of class being added to the element in a state

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const handler = () => setActive(!active);
  return (
    <div className={active ? "active" : ""} onClick={handler}>
      hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

just little css to test the presence of class

```css
.active {
color: red
}
```